# Email Template in Hebrew Language (Right to left)

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template

I want to send an HTML email template in Hebrew Language but i am not able to send it in right to left format. Can anyone please help me here by explaining how can i do it. Whenever i am pasting the text written in Right to Left format in Email template it is getting aligned in Left to Right format.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the [direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction) property in the CSS of the email, preferably inline. I have used this approach since 2003, and most email clients support it, so you should be fine. E.g.:

```
<div style="direction: rtl;">Your Hebrew text goes here</div>
```

You can also set it for entire email:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl" lang="he">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
זאת את העזרה ואמנות הגולשות. מיזם למתחילים מה עזה. אם מלא כלכלה בעברית, פיסיקה ומהימנה כלל דת. מה המחשב המלצת פוליטיקה ארץ, אם ביולוגיה אתנולוגיה סוציולוגיה בדף.
</body>
</html>
```

As I have done in [this example.](https://jsfiddle.net/kpoxdnga/)

Comment: I totally agree with @Lukas, using this approach for all templates.